# Up-to-date forecast for Korea cherry blossom time

Tags: south-korea, events

For Japan, https://www.japan-guide.com/sakura/ or https://www.jrailpass.com/blog/japan-cherry-blossom-forecast provide current and very detailed forecast for when cherries are expected to blossom depending on the region.

But when searching for the same information for Korea, I find posts from January or February about average dates. The latest I've seen and the only one specifically based on the 2018 weather is https://korea.stripes.com/travel/2018-nationwide-cherry-blossom-forecast-korea (February 28). Do Korean forecasts simply don't get updated as often as the Japanese ones (it certainly seems less popular than in Japan)?

Answer (score 3):

Cherry blossom in Korea is not a thing. People don't care, and certainly don't flock to gape at trees like they do in Japan. The fact that googling for "벚꽃 2018" gives you, as the first and second results, info in Korean about **Japanese** cherry blossom should be an indication.

[image]

Comment: Yet another spurious, idiotic downvote...